# I create view to show only specific city_name student fee but it give me student name with all fee

Tags: sql, oracle, view

```
create or replace view v_amount 
as 
     select s.s_name, s.s_fname, b.fee
     from student s, amount b
     where s.s_add = 'Peshawar'
     order by s.s_name;
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to explicit a relationship 1/1
Do you have some field with join S+B? look in the example for `key` fields

```
Create or replace view v_amount as select s.s_name,s.s_fname,b.fee 
from student s, amount b where s.s_add= 'Peshawar' AND s.key=b.key order by s.s_name;
```

If you don't understood post your CREATE for each table and all fields

Comment: yeah it's work with relationship but there is name who have no relation with account how can i get that name

Comment: Can you share your structure? I can't imagine it yet.

Comment: select s.s_name,s.s_fname, b.fee
from student s
left join account b
on s.s_id=b.s_id
where s.s_add='Peshawar'
order by s.s_name;

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a join clause so you are getting a CROSS JOIN.

You need something like

```
WHERE s.key = b.related_key
```

Using the syntax you are using.

Not sure what database you are using, but it is always best to use an ANSI join if it is supported.  Then you would get an error that made it clear what the problem is.  So if it is supported your query would be better written like this:

```
SELECT s.s_name, s.s_fname, b.fee
FROM student s
INNER JOIN amount b
ON s.key = b.related_key --you missed out this bit
WHERE s.s_add = 'Peshawar'
ORDER BY s.s_name;
```

If it were written this way you would have got an error message telling the ON clause was missing when you ran it.